# How to list branches with Magit

Tags: magit

How do I list the branches of a repository in Magit (i.e., the equivalent of `git branch --list`)? I expected to find this in the branch popup, but it seems to be neither there nor was I able to find it anywhere in the "Inspecting" section of the User's manual. What am I missing?

Comment: You can use tab key to open the local branch section and close the remote refs section -- and probably that is sticky or can be made sticky. It still fetches the remote refs which can take some time.

Comment: I would add, that anytime you find yourself wondering what options do I have press ? it will list available options. I know this is not really an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use `magit-show-refs`, bound by default to `y`.

Comment: Thanks! In my defense, the documentation for this entire popup doesn't mention the word *branch* even a single time...

Comment: Is there a way to limit this display to branches that are local, or being tracked (not list each and everything including remote refs?)

Answer (score 3):

To list branches and tags directly in your Magit status buffer, customize `magit-status-sections-hook` to add any/all of:

- `magit-insert-local-branches`
- `magit-insert-remote-branches`
- `magit-insert-tags`

Comment: I was actually just thinking about implementing those yesterday -- so thanks for the reminder that I have already done so. ;P

Comment: Haha, love it when that happens. Thanks for all your work on Magit!